# Pass Dynamic Values to ExchangeFilterFunction implementation in Spring WebClient

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I would like to use ExchangeFilterFunction and use some dynamic values in it to add to the request header.

```
 webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> {
                options.option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT);
                options.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            })).filter(userCredentialDelegationFilter).build();


public class UserCredentialDelegationFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {

    String orgId = // ** I would like to pass in this org id when callling get on web client.

    if (orgId != null) {
        request = ClientRequest.from(request).header(ClientConstants.HEADER_ORG_ID, securityContext.getOrgId()).build();
    }

    return next.exchange(request);
}
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Where you passing it in from? Will it be unique for each call? or where is it derived from?

Comment: It is derived from a pre defined list. I would like to pass it from the service that calls webClient.

Comment: @Learner, Did you figure out how to do this? WebClient beans are prototype by default, which I assume using a supplier/provider might work. Please share if you figured this out.